# how to change header navigation in the same component?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

my navigation initializeRoute screen is main.js

main.js have a onAuthStateCHange to detect a changes a current user

if current user is loggend main render component   "ChatScreen"
else main render a compoment  "LoginScreen"

the problem is  chatScreen and LoginScreen have the same navigation header bar (main header bar)

I need the loginscreen does not have a header and the chatScreen does

i have tried use a
static navigationOptions = {header: null} in login and chat, but de header we can se is header of main.js

if i set header null on main the chatScreen is without header too

```
 class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.unsubscriber = null;
    this.state = {
      user: null,
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscriber = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({ user });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.user) {
      return <Login />;
    }

    return <Chat />;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following in the main.js screen, you leave the navigation as you have it.

```js
// main.js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return { title: "", header: null 
  };
};
```

Then in the ChatScreen screen you personalize the header without depending on the react-navigation library, you do it in a personalized way.

```js
// Chat.js
class Chat extends Component {
render() {
return (
   <SafeAreaView>
    {/*header*/}
    <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Text>Chat</Text>
    </View>
    {/*body*/}
    <View>
    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
   }
} 
export default Chat;
```

The child component Chat must receive the navigation properties

```js
<Chat navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

and in turn the chat children should be passed.

```js
<SonChat navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```